# CSS truncate element with children

Tags: html, css

I have a flex container with childs span elements:

```
<div>
    <span class="truncate">
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </span>
    
    <span class="truncate">
        bbbb
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to truncate the whole element and not **an individual** part of it ( e.g the span ).

Is there any way to achieve this and still use the above structure? I want **one** ellipsis at the end.

```css
div {
    display: flex;
  background-color: hotpink;
    max-width: 200px;
}

span {
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

body {
    margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="truncate">
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </span>
    
    <span class="truncate">
        bbbb
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to truncate the whole element and not an individual part of it

If you want to truncate the `<div>`, the `<div>` should have the `.truncate` class.

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
  <span>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>
  <span>bbbb</span>
</div>
```

You can't have both `display: flex;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the same element.

That practically rules out having the `<div>` as flex parent, and the `<span>`s as flex children, and still get a coherent text overflow effect. `text-overflow` is an inline (!) text rendering feature. It requires a contiguous range of text that overflows a single container. Flex is practically block layout. You can't have it both ways, unfortunately.

Comment: where is the flex style?

Comment: @undefined It's not there because it's not relevant to the solution. If you want to have `display: flex;`, wrap the whole thing in another `<div>`. You can't have both `display: flex; ` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the same element.

Comment: It is relevant because as you see it doesn't work with flexbox. I want the div to be a flex parent.

Comment: @undefined *"If you want to have `display: flex;`, wrap the whole thing in another `<div>`.  You can't have both `display: flex;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the same element."*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I'll do what you say the span elements will not be flex childs

Comment: @undefined The way I understand it, you want to treat the two `<span>`s as one, and have a single `text-overflow: ellipsis;` that governs how they are displayed if there is not enough room. If that's correct, it rules out that doing `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on *each* of them. You *must* do it on an enclosing element. And I said *"You can't have both `display: flex;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the same element."* so that practically rules out having them as flex children. `text-overflow` is an inline (!) text rendering feature. Flex is practically block layout. You can't have both.

Comment: I see. So please add this explanation to the answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @undefined I can do that, but I'd try to find an alternative solution if you give a bit more context of what you're going for.

Comment: I don't have anything to add. I just wanted a flex container so that I can treat the spans as flex children.

Comment: @undefined Okay. Well, too bad it doesn't work that way right off the bat. There might be a chance with calculated CSS properties that approximates what you're trying to do, but it's hard to say (and it would take someone with stronger CSS fu than me to figure it out). For now I have added the basic state of affairs to the answer.